# Two nonlinear equations (quadratic) in two unknowns

Tags: nonlinear-system

I would like to solve the following system of equations:

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{r} a x^2 + b x y + c_1 x + c_2 y + d_1 = 0 ,\\ a y^2 + bxy + c_3 x + c_4 y + d_2 = 0 . \end{array} \right.  $$

Here, $a,b,c_i , d_i$ are known constants and I want to solve for $x$ and $y$.

Subtracting the two equations yield
$$ a (x^2 - y^2 ) + (c_1 - c_3) x + (c_2 - c_4 ) y + d_1 - d_2 = 0 $$ 
Though this does not give me much insight.

I think in general to solve a system of two quadratic equations in two unknowns is to do the following. For the first equation, regarding $y$ as a constant temporarily, we get 
$$ x = \dfrac{- (by + c_1 ) \pm \sqrt{(by + c_1)^2 - 4a (c_2 y + d_1)}}{ 2a}. $$ 
We can now plug this expression in the second equation and solve for $y$. This results in a fourth degree equation in $y$, which I do not know how to solve.

Any suggestions to tackle the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that if you assume that $y=x+k$ for some constant $k$, and substitute this value of $y$ in both equations, you will get 2 equations containing no $y$ and only powers of $x$ and constants. At this point you can compare coefficients of  powers of $x^{2}$, $x$ and the remaining constants to construct simpler to solve system.